# angular.js custom validation with invalid input values

Tags: angularjs, validation, email-validation

I put the project here :

but beacuse it need in directive to read from useremail.html file it not work at all. if anybody can put it in inline template and make it work would be great. I try it but I failed !

if you download and put all files in a server it will work.

my problem is that I dynamically add some validation to a field but when the field is invalid it remove the content.

```
    www.plnkr.co/edit/f91dJlloO364w8ERLI5V?p=preview
```

Comment: link not working. In addition could you improve the question? What did you try exactly? What's your expected result ?

Comment: it try to dynamically add some validator to input, and it do. for example required and email. but if it is not valid it sudenly remove the content of field !!!!!?

Comment: try this : http://plnkr.co/edit/f91dJlloO364w8ERLI5V